# Is there a name for this set/array operation?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, powerset, set-theory

Given the input array

```
[a,b,c,d,e]
```

and a 'join' function `(a,b) => (a+b)`

my code returns the following array of arrays, containing each possible variation obtained by applying the join function to various pairs of elements whilst maintaining the order:

```
[
  [a,b,c,d,e],
  [a,b+c,d,e],
  [a,b+c+d,e],
  [a,b,c+d,e],
  [a+b,c,d,e],
  [a+b,c+d,e],
  [a+b+c,d,e],
  [a+b+c+d,e],
  [a,b,c,d+e],
  [a,b+c,d+e],
  [a,b+c+d+e],
  [a,b,c+d+e],
  [a+b,c,d+e],
  [a+b,c+d+e],
  [a+b+c,d+e],
  [a+b+c+d+e],
]
```

Visually, what I'm trying to do is this:

[image: diagram of ordered partitions]

The code works but I have no idea what to call it - and would like to use a name that other developers familiar with this operation will understand, should such a name exist. It's not a power set but it is something similar... does this particular set/array operation have a name?

EDIT: OK. They're not **permutations**; permutations would all be 5-element arrays in different orders `[[a,b,c,d,e], [e,d,c,b,a], [a,d,b,c,e], ...]`

They're not **partitions**, since any subset can only contain adjacent elements of the input. - in other words, partitions would allow this:

[image: diagram depicting partitions of non-adjacent elements]

(This probably arises from pure set theory having no notion of an ordered set.)

They're not **combinations** since every element of the output uses every member of the input set exactly once.

I think `myArray.OrderedPartitions((a,b) => (a+b))` is probably a suitably succinct and explanatory.

Comment: Why `[a+b+c+d+e]` is missing?

Comment: @Landei my mistake :) Edited the question to include the missing permutation.

Comment: This has to do with partial sums or segment sums, however, that is not an accurate description.

Comment: The operation creates permutations. Why nit "permute"?

Comment: off topic here, perhaps this should be on programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: They are most definitely _not_ permutations of any kind! Permutations are by definition reorderings of the same set of items. Here however, there are no two lists with the same items.

Comment: CAn you describe what you are doing in a few words? If not can you describe the intent in a few words? It seems that it is doing something like "GetAllJoins" (ie it is getting all the sets derived from applying a join to adjacent elements of the input set or any other set it contains)... I've definitely not seen anything like this before so don't think it has a defined name that is going to be that useful...

Comment: Something like constrained partitioning, except that you only have one group with cardinality > 1 (i.e. I see no `[ a+b, c+d, e ]`).

Comment: @Iserni - omission on my part.

Comment: I would call this [Order-dependent Integer Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).  It's basically equivalent to all the ways you can write a number as a sum of integers:
`1+1+1+1+1
1+1+1+2
1+1+2+1
1+1+3
1+2+1+1
1+2+2
...`

Comment: what program did you use to create the diagrams?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker - the diagrams were drawn in Visio (http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/visio/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mbeckish said in a comment, those sets are (once an order on the original set is fixed) isomorphic to order-dependent integer partitions, which apparently are commonly referred to as [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29). There are exactly 2<sup>n-1</sup> compositions of every set. For every `1` ≤ `k` ≤ `n`, there are exactly `(n-1) choose (k-1)` compositions of `n` elements into `k` sets, preserving the order of the set you started out with. To visualize it, think of the elements of your set put in order and a space between elements that are neighbours in that order; think of your example as `A|B|C|D|E`. You will notice that there are exactly `n-1` possible borders. To create a k-composition, you need only choose `k-1` of those possible borders, which may or may not be the way you generated your sets. Summing all `(n-1) choose (k-1)` for `k` from `1` to `n` then gives us 2<sup>n-1</sup> as the number of possible compositions.

Comment: Nice explanation. It may be worth adding that the summation is equal to `2^(n-1)`.

Comment: They would indeed appear to be compositions. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

After your edit - these are all **partitions** of an array (and their count is 2^(n-1), because you can replace any divider(colon) by joiner(+)).

Note - these are array partitions, not set partitions.

Answer (score 1):

[The poster's major edit made my answer obsolete, this was about the original question posted:]
The online encyclopedia of integer sequences mentions these briefly as 'interval subsets'.
(http://oeis.org/A000124)
I would stick with this one, it's quite descriptive.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is that descriptive of what it is doing (in that if I saw the name I'd have no idea what I'd expect the function to do - I Can see how the name fits after a lot of though).

Answer (score 0):

It's a directed tree that points away from the root node:

[image]

It's important to note that you do not declare the order of your sets important, only that order is maintained with each set. The python code to generate your "partitions" via your "join":

```
A = map(list, list('abcde'))

def join(A):
    B = []
    for x1,x2 in zip(A,A[1:]):
        B.append((x1,x2,sorted(list(set(x1+x2)))))
    return B
def label(x):
    return '+'.join(x)

# Draw the graph with networkx
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()

while len(A)>1:
    B = join(A)
    for x1,x2,pair in B:
        print label(x1), label(pair)
        G.add_edge(label(x1),label(pair))
        G.add_edge(label(x2),label(pair))
    A = [x[2] for x in B]

nx.write_dot(G,'test.dot')

# Render the graph to an image
import os
os.system('dot -Tpng test.dot > test.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about myArray.possibleChainings() or myArray.possibleLinkings() ?

The idea is that it looks like you are chaining or linking at least
two elements together. I find it also intuitive because you cannot
chain or link elements together which are not neighbors.